# Dynamic slide php bootstrap

Tags: php, loops, bootstrap-4

I made dynamic carousel but if I include 'active-item' in loop it not working, this solution is silly but handle. How can I include 'active-item' properly?

```
<form class="form" action="routes.php" method="POST">

<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide bg-light text-primary" data-ride="carousel">
<div class="carousel-inner"

<div class="carousel-item active" >
<img class="d-block m-auto " style="width: 800px; height:600px; " alt="There is <?php echo count($photos);?> photos">
</div> 
<?php foreach ($photos as $photo) {?>
<div class="carousel-item">
<img class="d-block m-auto" style="width: 800px; height:600px;" src="../css/image/<?php echo $photo['pic_name']?>" alt="<?php echo $photo['pic_name']?>">
</div>
<?php }?>
</div>
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
<span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
<span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's important to write 'item-active' properly, this is how I handle it, and its work

```
  <div class="carousel-inner" >

  <?php $i=1; foreach ($photos as $photo) {?>

  <div class="carousel-item <?php if ($i==1)echo 'active'?>"><?php $i++;?>
  <img class="d-block m-auto" style="width: 800px; height:600px;" src="../css/image/<?php echo $photo['pic_name']?>" alt="<?php echo $photo['pic_name']?>">
  </div>
  <?php }?>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a php code as below

```
$active = ($photo== 1)? 'active-itme':'';
```

and echo it in the class like

```
class='<?php echo $active?>'
```

So it will be triggered only on the first slider image. Since you need the first slider image to be active.

Comment: <div class="carousel-inner" >
   <?php $i=1; foreach ($fotografije as $foto) {?>
  
    <div class="carousel-item <?php if ($i==1)echo 'active'?>"><?php $i++;?>
      <img class="d-block m-auto" style="width: 800px; height:600px;" src="../css/image/<?php echo $foto['naziv_slike']?>" alt="<?php echo $foto['naziv_slike']?>">
    </div>
    <?php }?>
  </div>  Tnx, I did it like this :D